Changing selected value in dropdowns dynamically, but the dropdowns are also dynamically populated based on previous selections
I want to change the selected values of the dropdowns dynamically with the updateDropdowns() function that i created. Almost all of the dropdowns are dynamically populated based on previous selections.
The problem is only those dropdowns that dont rely on previous selection have their values changed.
this is my updateDropdowns() function:
function updateDropdowns(details) {
        const startT = details.startTime.substring(0, 5);
        const endT = details.endTime.substring(0, 5);

        $('#courses').val(details.courseCode).change();
        console.log('Course set:', details.courseCode);
    
        $('#subjects').val(details.subjectCode).change();
        console.log('Subject set:', details.subjectCode);
    
        $('#sections').val(details.sectionCode).change();
        console.log('Section set:', details.sectionCode);
    
        $('#rooms').val(details.roomID).change();
        console.log('Room set:', details.roomID);
    
        $('#days').val(details.dayOfWeek).change();
        console.log('Day set:', details.dayOfWeek);
    
        $('#teachers').val(details.idNumber).change();
        console.log('Teacher set:', details.idNumber);
    
        $('#startTime').val(startT).change();
        console.log('Start time set:', startT);
    
        $('#endTime').val(endT).change();
        console.log('End time set:', endT);
    }

I also tried putting delays but it only made it not display anything at all.
function updateDropdowns(details) {
    
    const startT = details.startTime.substring(0, 5);
    const endT = details.endTime.substring(0, 5);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#courses').val(details.courseCode).change();
        console.log('Course set:', details.courseCode);
    }, 300);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#subjects').val(details.subjectCode).change();
        console.log('Subject set:', details.subjectCode);
    }, 600);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#sections').val(details.sectionCode).change();
        console.log('Section set:', details.sectionCode);
    }, 900);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#rooms').val(details.roomID).change();
        console.log('Room set:', details.roomID);
    }, 1200);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#days').val(details.dayOfWeek).change();
        console.log('Day set:', details.dayOfWeek);
    }, 1500);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#teachers').val(details.idNumber).change();
        console.log('Teacher set:', details.idNumber);
    }, 1800);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#startTime').val(startT).change();
        console.log('Start time set:', startT);
    }, 2100);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#endTime').val(endT).change();
        console.log('End time set:', endT);
    }, 2400);
}


The issue arises because dynamically populated dropdowns often depend on asynchronous operations triggered by change(). You must ensure that each dropdown is populated before setting its value by chaining updates based on events or using Promises.
Given that the result is not as good as it should be (probably you need to refactor completely this structure), a working example can be:
function updateDropdowns(details) {
    const startT = details.startTime.substring(0, 5);
    const endT = details.endTime.substring(0, 5);

    $('#courses').val(details.courseCode).change().on('change', function () {
        $('#subjects').val(details.subjectCode).change().on('change', function () {
            $('#sections').val(details.sectionCode).change().on('change', function () {
                $('#rooms').val(details.roomID).change().on('change', function () {
                    $('#days').val(details.dayOfWeek).change().on('change', function () {
                        $('#teachers').val(details.idNumber).change();
                        $('#startTime').val(startT).change();
                        $('#endTime').val(endT).change();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

This ensures each dropdown waits for its dependencies to update before proceeding.
As already said, this is not an optimal solution and likely inefficient, but it should give the good track for such issue but I suggest to refine the code structure and flow.

Callback Hell

@PetəíŕdtheWizard yep, as I said in the answer, it is not optimal, but it should explain the flow. however it must be refactored
